# Why is span defaultly designed to have a width shorter than that of its parent element, when span is used to contain an <input type="text">

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <span>
    <input type="text">
  </span>
</body>
```

My question is very simple. Why has div the same width as that of its parent, whereas span has a shorter width than that of its parent? i.e. if body's width is 1000px, then div has 1000px as well, but span has only 300px(fluctuate from different browsers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div` is a block-level element, while `span` is an inline element. Block-level elements will take up the width of the parent element, while inline elements will not.

For example, `a` is an inline element. You wouldn't expect, nor want, it to take up the whole parent:

```
Some text <a href="#">and an engaging link</a>.
```

However, `p` is a block-level element. It *will* take up the entire parent (and it won't tolerate other block-level elements to be beside it):

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Other text -- not on the same line.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<div>` tag is a block level element while `<span>` tag is the inline element.

- Block level elements will expand its width to 100% of the parent item and produce a break line.
- Inline elements only wrap the HTML elements (content), so its width is flexible according to the content

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is an inline element, whereas `<div>` is a block element. Inline elements do not expand to fill their parent element.